# List projects that does not hire anyone with usage of NOT IN

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have two tables.

Projects

```
**p_id** | manager | name |   date   |    
t2          andrew   CSO    11/12/13
```

Employees

```
id | name | surname | id_division | sallary | **project**    
1    kate   black          57        1500        t2
```

And column project and p_id are corresponding entires.

I want to list all projects that don't employee anyone. So if i get it right, there is not p_id of this project in Employees table in project column and i want to do it with the usage of NOT IN.

I tried to do it like this but i doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE p_id NOT IN 
(SELECT project FROM Employees);
```

It doesn't select any row. But there is one project that doesn't have employee because he is in Projects table and have p_id that doesn't exist in Employees table in project row.

Comment: Do you have any `NULL` records in `project` column ?

Comment: You got the answer down

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise against using `NOT IN` with subqueries.  If *any* row returned by the subquery has a `NULL` value, then nothing is ever returned.

Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM projects p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees e where e.project = p.p_id);
```

This has the semantics that you expect.

You *can* use `NOT IN`, if you filter out `NULL` values:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM projects p
WHERE p.p_id NOT IN (SELECT e.project FROM Employees e WHERE e.project IS NOT NULL);
```

But I recommend `NOT EXISTS` because it is less prone to coding or data errors.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful!

Comment: @qamyk - Adding to Gordon's answer: If the list in the NOT IN condition includes NULL, then nothing will be selected. There is no value that is GUARANTEED to be different from NULL. (More formally: `x not in (a, b, NULL)` means `x<> a and x<>b and x<>NULL`. The last one evaluates to UNKNOWN, not to TRUE - and then the entire expression, linked with AND, can never be TRUE, because at least one of the terms is UNKNOWN, not TRUE).